# Git with Password rather than public key

Tags: linux, git

I have a git server running for a small group to check into and I am wondering if there is a way to set it up so the user can log in with their password rather than having to use a public key?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why would you want to use passwords instead of keys? Keys are superior in nearly all respects. Yes, they take a bit more work to get set up, but that's a one-time task, after which things are a *lot* simpler for the user and more secure.

Comment: I second ErikA's comment, which is especially true for a group of developers. Surely they are technically capable of getting keys set up? (If not, then they shouldn't be working on your project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a [smart https transport](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) on the Git server, which means you can use the Apache authentication mechanism (which can be linked to a LDAP for instance, allowing you to use your LDAP login/password).

> Smart-HTTP is basically just enabling the new CGI script that is provided with Git called **`git-http-backend`** on the server.
>   This CGI will read the path and headers sent by the revamped git fetch and git push binaries who have learned to communicate in a specific way with a smart server.